# python: unhashable type error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#80>", line 1, in <module>
    do_work()
  File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile080410.py", line 14, in do_work
    populate_frequency5(e,data)
  File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile080410.py", line 157, in populate_frequency5
    data=medications_minimum3(data,[drug.upper()],1)
  File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile080410.py", line 120, in medications_minimum3
    counter[row[11]]+=1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am getting the above error on this line:

```
data=medications_minimum3(data,[drug.upper()],1)
```

(I have also tried drug.upper() without brackets)

Here is a preview of this function:

```
def medications_minimum3(c,drug_input,sample_cutoff): #return sample cut off for # medications/physician
  d=[]
  counter=collections.defaultdict(int)
  for row in c:
    counter[row[11]]+=1
  for row in c:
    if counter[row[11]]>=sample_cutoff:
      d.append(row) 
  write_file(d,'/pythonwork/medications_minimum3.csv')
  return d
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

I know that what must be wrong is the way I am calling this function, because I call this function from a different location and it works fine:

```
d=medications_minimum3(c,drug_input,50)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why do you have the square brackets around `[drug.upper()]` in the failing call?

Comment: And it's also not used in the function, there is no reference to drug_input

Comment: @jcubic: Good catch.  That probably means the code has been so heavily edited for posting here as to be worthless.

Comment: With filenames like `readthefile080410.py` I'm guessing you're not using version control.  There is no excuse not to start using one **NOW**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132520/good-excuses-not-to-use-version-control if you don't believe me.

Comment: @sdolan which source control do u recommned for python in windows?

Comment: Any version control is better than no version control.  There are multiple questions on StackOverflow which attempt to answer this.  "It depends" but any one of Mercurial, Git, or even Subversion should be fine.  Some people like Bazaar and Darcs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think converting to a tuple is the right answer. You need go and look at where you are calling the function and make sure that `c` is a list of list of strings, or whatever you designed this function to work with

For example you might get this error if you passed `[c]` to the function instead of `c`

Answer (score 16):

```
counter[row[11]]+=1
```

You don't show what `data` is, but apparently when you loop through its rows, `row[11]` is turning out to be a `list`. Lists are mutable objects which means they cannot be used as dictionary keys. Trying to use `row[11]` as a key causes the `defaultdict` to complain that it is a mutable, i.e. unhashable, object.

The easiest fix is to change `row[11]` from a `list` to a `tuple`. Either by doing

```
counter[tuple(row[11])] += 1
```

or by fixing it in the caller before `data` is passed to `medications_minimum3`. A tuple simply an immutable list, so it behaves exactly like a list does except you cannot change it once it is created.

Comment: thank very much for your help, the thing is as mentioned in the question, it is called from a different place and it works fine

Comment: Right. If `c` contains tuples then the function works fine. If it contains lists then the function fails. It all depends on what the caller passes in.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim Garrison said in the comment, no obvious reason why you'd make a one-element list out of `drug.upper()` (which implies drug is a string).

But that's not your error, as your function `medications_minimum3()` doesn't even use the second argument (something you should fix).

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` usually means that you are trying to use a list as a hash argument (like for accessing a dictionary). I'd look for the error in `counter[row[11]]+=1` -- are you sure that `row[11]` is of the right type? Sounds to me it might be a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
  File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile080410.py", line 120, in medications_minimum3
    counter[row[11]]+=1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

`row[11]` is unhashable.  It's a list.  That is precisely (and only) what the error message means.  You might not like it, but that is the error message.

Do this

```
counter[tuple(row[11])]+=1
```

Also, simplify.

```
d= [ row for row in c if counter[tuple(row[11])]>=sample_cutoff ]
```

Comment: the thing is as mentioned in the question, it is called from a different place and it works fine, counter is a collection

Comment: "the thing is as mentioned in the question"?  What?  `counter` is a collection.  Correct.  `row[11]` is a list.  That's what your error message says.

Comment: Would be good to add some explanation around what is meant by the error, i.e. what hashable means, what's hashable, what's not, why not, etc