# Is there any python module that will count frequency of (list, list) tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, counter

I have a list of tuples, which are each a pair of lists. So my data looks like:

```
mylist = [(['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar']),(['bar', 'bar'],['bar', 'bar']),(['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar'])]
```

I want to do something like:

```
pprint.pprint(Counter(mylist).mostCommon(1)) # returns {(['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', bar']) : count 2}
```

However when I do `Counter(mylist)` python is throwing an error, "unhashable type list" -- like in this question. [python: unhashable type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410206/python-unhashable-type-error)

I know I could roll my own counter [like here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/36420-counter-items-lists-lists) but it would certainly be much slower than Python's. Is there any python module that will do this this for me?

Answer (score 6):

Simply convert your lists to tuples if you want to count them by exact contents:

```
Counter((tuple(l1), tuple(l2)) for l1, l2 in mylist).most_common(1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mylist = [(['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar']), (['bar', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar']), (['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar'])]
>>> Counter((tuple(l1), tuple(l2)) for l1, l2 in mylist).most_common(1)[0]
((('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'bar')), 2)
```

Now your contents are hashable and can be counted. You can always turn the keys back into lists if you have to.

Comment: @SukritKalra: yes, I was hooked up in correcting the OP input sample first. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> Counter(tuple(map(tuple, elem)) for elem in mylist).most_common(1)
[((('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'bar')), 2)]
```